# jQuery remote validation always returning false

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I have the below code for implementing a very basic login system on my site (using jQuery Mobile). The problem is that, when submitting the form through jQuery Mobile (and therefore using the validator), the validator always returns false and throws an error, even if the password is correct. When I wrote a separate form with nothing other than the two textboxes and a submit button and ran it directly to the validation script, it returned the correct value of true or false depending on the given password. What's wrong with the jQuery script that causes it to always return false?

HTML/JS:

```
<form action="logins.php" method="POST" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" data-ajax="false">
<label for="email" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address" />
<label for="pass" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value="" placeholder="Password" />
<input class="submit" data-role="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form><br>
<br>
<a href="#index" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Return to home page</a>
<script>
    $('#login').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
        $('#loginForm').validate({
            onkeyup: false,
            onclick: false,
            onfocusout: false,
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                pass: {
                    required: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "passcheck.php",
                        type: "post"
                    }
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "You must enter an email address.",
                    email: "You must enter a valid email address."
                },
                pass: {
                    required: "You must enter a password.",
                    remote: "Your username/password combination is incorrect."
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP (passcheck.php):

```
<?php
    require("common.php");

$query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = :email";
$query_params = array(':email' => $_POST['email']);

try { 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute($query_params);
} catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    die("Failed to run query."); 
}

$hash = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if(crypt($_POST['pass'], $hash) === $hash){
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: The reason it isn't working is because the validator is NOT passing along both the e-mail address AND password - it is ONLY trying to validate the password remotely. See my answer below on how to handle this - you need to use submitHandler in order for both the be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the submitHandler to write a function to handle the actual checking of the username/password via AJAX using AJAX Form: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api. 
You don't have to use AJAX Form and can write your own method to handle the login checking using the jQuery ajax() method, but AJAX Form has it prewritten for you.

Also, you don't need the onkeyup, onblur, etc. there - all you need is onsubmit set to true. Your code  should look like this:

```
<script>
    $('#login').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
        $('#loginForm').ajaxForm(); // Set as an AJAX Form - See Documentation Above
        $('#loginForm').validate({
            onsubmit: true,
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                pass: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "You must enter an email address.",
                    email: "You must enter a valid email address."
                },
                pass: {
                    required: "You must enter a password.",
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $("#loginForm").ajaxSubmit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Note, my code above isn't just "Drop in and work" it is an example using a pre-build library. This libray uses the action on the form when it submits. If you want to use your "passcheck.php" to check the user/pass AND have the form action go to a different place, you will need to configure the form that way OR write your own simple AJAX call to handle that inside the submitHandler.

Comment: Shoot, I didn't even think about that. I ended up validating it a different way--I validated it server-side and redirected it to the logged in portal or an incorrect page depending on the result. Thank you!